# Intersection of an element and a set containing that element.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I found in a text, the following notation:

> $\lbrace 1, 2, 3, 4 \rbrace\cap 2= \lbrace  2 \rbrace$

To my knowledge, a set and an element cannot be concatenated by a set intersection i.e., the set intersection is defined for two sets, but neither for two elements nor for combining a set and an element. Therefore, the correct notation i think for the above line is

> $\lbrace 1, 2, 3, 4 \rbrace\cap \lbrace 2\rbrace= \lbrace  2 \rbrace$.

Comment: You are correct.  The first notation is nonsense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are completely right, and this is most likely a typo in the text.

Sometimes, the natural numbers themselves do denote a set. So for example, 2 would denote the set $\{0, 1\}$. In general, $n = \{0, 1, \ldots, n-1\}$. This is under the interpretation of natural numbers as [ordinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number). In that case, we could make sense of the first intersection and we would have:
$$
\{1,2,3,4\} \cap 2 = \{1,2,3,4\} \cap \{0,1\} = \{1\}.
$$